# Timed out to get from API - PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to get data from an API using PHP,

First I use this php code to get it:

```
$uri = 'API-URL';
$response = file_get_contents($uri, false);
$results = json_decode($response);
var_dump($results->);
```

this code is work perfectly on Localhost and server and after a week the page still refreshed and after some minute I get this error

> file_get_contents(API-URL): failed to open stream: Connection timed
>   out

**PS: this problem just on server, on localhost work perfectly**

with some search on net I found CURL, I try to do it but the same problem,

page still refreshed and finally I get NULL

```
$uri = 'API-URL';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results = json_decode($response);
var_dump($results);
```

is there any solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Are you registered to use this API?

Comment: Sounds like the admin used DROP instead of REJECT when blocking your IP

Comment: Have you tried cURL from the commandline or `wget`? If that shows the same issue, you have shown conclusively that neither PHP nor cURL is the issue, so you can just as well remove all the PHP code. Without that, there is basically no information left, so your question can't be answered (except by guessing) or reproduced. In other words, you first need to work on the problem description itself a lot more before you can ask here. Please read [ask] and also provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes sir

Comment: Did you register your LIVE site as well as your development site?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm sorry for that, because I'm beginner on English and on the same I don't know what's the error exactly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understood exactly what you mean, but the codes is work perfectly on the first time and after a week I get this error. first I think that the IP is blocked but when I contact the support API they answer me that the error is on our side.